# Cannot deploy a dacpac from code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, dacpac

I have a dacpac on my local machine I am trying to deploy it using code and it fails. with the following error 
[image: error message]

I code I am using to deploy the dacpac is as follows

```
private static void CreateDatabase()
        {
            using (var dacPackage = DacPackage.Load(DacPacFullPath))
            {
                var dacServices = new DacServices(Shared.Environment.Settings.RadanDbNameOrConnectionString());
                dacServices.Deploy(dacPackage, DatabaseName, true);
            }
        }
```

The things I have checked

- DacPacFullPath is correct
- dacServices is correct i.e, the connectionstring is formed correctly.
- Used the credentials used in the connection string to login onto SQL and it 
  works fine
- I manually deployed the dacpac in management studio and it works

I am using SQL Server 2016 and Visual Studio 2015 Detailed info as follows

### SQL Server

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      13.0.16106.4
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                    13.0.1700.441
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     10.0.16299.15
Microsoft MSXML                                             3.0 4.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                                 9.11.16299.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                                    4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                                            6.3.16299
```

### Visual Studio 2015

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02556

Installed Version: Professional

LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2015   00322-40000-00000-AA922
Microsoft LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2015

Visual Basic 2015   00322-40000-00000-AA922
Microsoft Visual Basic 2015

Visual C# 2015   00322-40000-00000-AA922
Microsoft Visual C# 2015

Visual C++ 2015   00322-40000-00000-AA922
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   7.0.20622.1
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)   14.1.11107.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0
For additional information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

Common Azure Tools   1.8
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

JavaScript Language Service   2.0
JavaScript Language Service

JavaScript Project System   2.0
JavaScript Project System

JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2016.2.2    Build 106.0.20160913.91321
JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For more information about ReSharper Ultimate, visit http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper. Copyright © 2018 JetBrains, Inc.

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools

NuGet Package Manager   3.4.4
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.60519.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

TypeScript   1.8.36.0
TypeScript tools for Visual Studio
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it from .sqlproj? If it is - what are connection values in project / properties / sql * tab? You might also need SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT).

Comment: @JustinasMarozas - No it is a Visual Studio 2015 project and yes SSDT is installed. I have updated the question to now include whats installed on my visual studio.

Comment: The final exception *will* typically be highly uninformative. Hook up an event handler to [`DacServices.Message`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.dacservices.message) and stash the output somewhere (or write it directly to the console, depending on your project type).